# C# How do I convert two or more integers into a date?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert two integers for instance 28 and 03 into a date like "28.03".
The integers should be input from the user and then converted to the date.
Also, how do I add days to the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an implementation for your example:

```
public static string GetDateString(int month, int day)
{
    return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day).ToString("dd.MM");
}
```

To add days to a date you can use the `DateTime.AddDays()` method:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime otherDate = date.AddDays(7);
```

The links mentioned by @Giorgi and @D. Petrov are also very useful.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example based on your comment.

```
class ConsoleApp
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string formattedDate = GetDateString(month, day);

        Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);

        // You cannot initialize a DateTime struct only with month and day.
        // Because Year is not relevant we use the current year.
        DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);
        DateTime otherDate = date.AddDays(5);

        Console.WriteLine(GetFormattedDate(otherDate));
    }

    public static string GetFormattedDate(DateTime date)
    {
        // The ToString() method accepts any custom date format string.
        // Here is how you can create a custom date format string:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

        // dd: days in two digits
        // MM: months in two digits
        return date.ToString("dd.MM");
    }

    public static string GetDateString(int month, int day)
    {
        // Here we construct a DateTime struct
        DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);

        // Now we extract only the day and month parts.
        return GetFormattedDate(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me because I only need the two integers turned into the corresponding day and month without the year, seconds and so forth. 28 and 03 into a date like "28.03".

Comment: Updated my answer with the date format string. (Replaced `"MM.dd"` with `"dd.MM"`). `GetDateString(3, 28)` will return `"28.03"` string value so it definitely does what you need.

Comment: public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        
         new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day).ToString("dd.MM");
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime otherDate = date.AddDays(5);
            Console.WriteLine(otherDate);
        }

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't get this. It returns to me the date + plus the year + plus the hours. With input of "25" and "04", this is what's returned: 7.5.2016 ?. 14:48:28

Comment: Plus, we are talking about a random date, so I don't think Now.Year should be used.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov, I updated my answer. I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful!

Answer (score 3):

Well if 28 is day and 03 month - you can pass these parameters to the constructor of [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure object. Once you initialize a `DateTime` object there are various ways to convert it as string. It also has [AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: I know I can pass these parameters, but the data is not entered by me. I need to write a program that accepts two integers from the user and then turns them into a date. 28 and 03 into a date like "28.03"

Comment: I think it is not important from where the data comes from (entered by you or anybody else) when you have a method accepting two integers that creates a `DateTime` instance and call its `.ToString()` method with the appropriate custom format string and finally returns this string to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

There is plenty of documentation about what you need (in particular - the `DateTime` structure). The most relevant information about your current need and the different ways to format yor string with the date you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx 
But as I mentioned before, there is plenty of information in the web.